# AttributeType::Number giving validation error "Must be an integer"

Tags: validation, models, attributetype

So I have a model attribute `attributeName` with an `AttributeType::Number`

I haven't implemented any personal validation rules yet, however when I run:
`model->validate()`, 
its giving me a `"attributeName must be an integer"` error.

Is this just the default validation rule of the `AttributeType::Number`?  and if so, is there anything I can do to make it accept floats?

I am trying to use this attribute for a price, I should note.

[CNumberValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberValidator) has an `integerOnly` attribute, so I tried setting `'integerOnly'=>false` in the attribute declaration, to no avail. Not sure if its relevant, I think I might be grasping at straws. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really documented anywhere, but `AttributeType::Number` can accept an array of options, including `min`, `max` and `decimal`.  You're looking for the last one.

```
AttributeType::Number => array('min' => 0, 'max' => 10, 'decimals' => 2);
```